# Can I View My Advertising ID?

Tags: iphone, ios, privacy

Is it possible to see my Advertising ID?

The [Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205223) states

> ...
>   When Limit Ad Tracking is enabled on iOS 10 or later, the Advertising
>   Identifier is replaced with a non-unique value of all zeros to prevent
>   the serving of targeted ads. It is automatically reset to a new random
>   identifier if you disable Limit Ad Tracking.
>
> You can also choose to reset your Advertising Identifier, in which
>   case your device will generate a new random identifier. ...

This tells me it changes, but as a user and owner of a phone, is there a way to see the value stored in the Advertising Identifier?

This applies to an iPhone 7 Plus running ios 13.3.1, but could be for any iPhone running ios 13.

Comment: Are you asking this as a user, an app developer or as another role? What do you intend to do with the ID once you know it?

Comment: As a user, Question updated.